# How to remove duplicate records in hive external tables using python UDF?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have created external table with text files of having 200GB of data. in that there might be possibility of duplicate records, in that case i have to throw exception.

I guess using group by we can eliminate duplicates but in my case i have to abort the process when duplicate records exist.

Please let me know, How to handle this problem? Is it possible with python UDF or in Hive (version 0.13) itself we can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to check the existence of duplicated  data? Give the data schema and sample data if so.

Comment: Yes I want to check existence of dupliocate data and if any duplicates found then have to abort the process with proper error message. The table contains 23 columns. The data type details are 8 decimal (25,6), 5 string, 10 integers. Hope we can assume any sample data to meet this criteria.